# Is there a way to find the total number of tokens in circulation generated by a minting policy

Tags: plutus

I've wrote a minting policy that will allow minting of some token, the token can then by transferred of course to other wallets.

Is there a way to find the total number of tokens in circulation?
(ideally from plutus code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As plutus does not have access to the entire blockchain, it would not, unless you create some kind of a counter in the minting script.